# Xarray long-format to wide-format - equivalent to Pandas' pivot

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I'm looking for a way to make a pivot table in Xarray, similar to Pandas' `.pivot` or `set_index([...]).unstack()`.

Basically, I have some tabular data with 3 columns:

[image: Data]

And I would like to (in Xarray) convert this into the wide format through pivoting or the s`et_index([...]).unstack()` operations as shown here via Pandas:

[image: pivot table]

Of course I can do this by first converting the data from long- to wide format via Pandas and then loading it into Xarray:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index(['price','date']).unstack()
x = xr.DataArray(df.values,dims=("price","date"),
                 coords={"price":df.index,
                         "date":df.columns.get_level_values(1)},
                 attrs={"long_name":"volume","units":'BTC'})
```

which gives the following results:

[image: result]

But I would really like a way to do all of this without using Pandas, since I would also like to leverage Xarray's native Dask support.

Comment: Just a side note, it is usually better to add code instead of images as they can be removed by time and the question wont be useful for future readers. Always keep in mind when posting that your post might eventually help somebody else having similar problem.

Comment: Does xarray's stack / unstack do what you want? For anything more specific, please post a reproducible example